# Does the Condition Operator Evaluate Bitwise for indexed part selection

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, conditional-operator

I wish to choose between bits of two indexed part selections using the values of each of the bits of another indexed part selection. Put in code that looks like:

```
output[idx*WIDTH+:WIDTH] = (condition[idx*WIDTH+:WIDTH]) ? (expression1[idx*WIDTH+:WIDTH) : expression2[idx*WIDTH+:WIDTH];
```

e.g. Looking at a single bit, if `condition[idx*WIDTH] = 1` I want `output[idx*WIDTH]` to contain the value of `expression1[idx*WIDTH]` and if `condition[idx*WIDTH] = 0`, I want `output[idx*WIDTH]` to contain the value of `expression2[idx*WIDTH]`.

Is this legal in System Verilog? If not, is there a better way to achieve the same functionality while keeping the indexed part select for the buses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional expression (or *predicate*) is Boolean—it is *true* or *false*. To evaluate the predicate bitwise, you can either use a `foreach` loop

```
for(int I=idx*WIDTH;I<(idx+1)*WIDTH;I++)
    output[I] = condition[I] ? expression1[I] : expression2[I];
```

or an equivalent mux equation:

```
output[idx*WIDTH+:WIDTH] = 
    condition[idx*WIDTH+:WIDTH] & expression1[idx*WIDTH+:WIDTH) |
    ~condition[idx*WIDTH+:WIDTH] & expression2[idx*WIDTH+:WIDTH];
```